# Limiting an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've got an IAM policy on a current bucket that will list all buckets and allow full access to a specified bucket inside of the S3 account. Problem is, I want to now limit upload to specific folders only within the specified bucket. Is there a way to do this and specify only top level folders can be uploaded into, rather than listing specific folders in the policy? Here's what I currently have:

```
{
"Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME",
  "Condition": {}
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion",
    "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:PutObjectAclVersion"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME/*",
  "Condition": {}
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {}
}
 ]
}
```

Comment: `I've got a bucket policy`. Your policy looks like an `IAM policy` and **NOT** `Bucket Policy`. Bucket policy will always contain "Principle" which is missing in you policy. First, clarify which policy are you referring to.

Comment: You're right, it is an IAM policy. Not sure that I realized that there was a difference.